# Authentication and Authorization access control in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, mobile, authorization

Are there Tips & Techniques that work well with Authentication and Authorization access control in AngularJS... for mobile applications?

Comment: I've been looking a lot into this lately and from my findings, it seems that web tokens are quite popular. http://jwt.io/

Comment: i am already using OAuth2.0 for authentication and authorization and it goes very well with angularJS